# Error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name. What could be the issue here?

Tags: javascript

I am getting a type error:

> Error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name
> at HTMLFormElement.loginDataHandler (index.js:77:9)

I have searched google for hours now and tried all the suggested solutions but noe seem to be working on my end.

I am stuck, can't make any progress.

```js
function loginDataHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  loginObject = {
    email: emailInput.value,
    passwordInput: passwordInput.value
  };
  console.log(loginObject);
  const newLocal = "https://mawingu.cbaloop.com/cba/api/v1/access/login";
  fetch(newLocal, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(loginObject),
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Contr"ol-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:5500',
        " Access-Control-Allow-Methods ": "POST",
        ' Authorization ': ` None  `,
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With",
        'referrerPolicy': 'no-referrer'
      },
    })
    .then(
      res => res.json()
    )
    .then(
      data => console.log(data)
    )
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error:', error);
    });
}
```

what could be the issue?

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue, but you have a bunch of whitespace where there probably shouldn't be any. `' Authorization '` should probably be `'Authorization'` for example

Comment: I did away with the spaces but still got myself into another error

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the following:

```
'Access-Contr"ol-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:5500',
" Access-Control-Allow-Methods ": "POST",
' Authorization ': ` None  `,
```

it will submit the request.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but unfornately when I do that I run into another error that would want me to include the just removed headers.

Comment: `index.html:1 Access to fetch at 'https://mawingu.cbaloop.com/cba/api/v1/access/login' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
index.js:77          POST https://mawingu.cbaloop.com/cba/api/v1/access/login net::ERR_FAILED`

Comment: `headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With",
                'referrerPolicy': 'no-referrer'
             },`

Comment: This is because you need that the server will return the right CORS headers (you can not bypass it from the client).
If it's development environment, you can use to test it:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere

Comment: Let me try it out! Though I have no control of the backend API.

Comment: Do you any alternative? Since I'm working on a vanilla JS?

Comment: The cors-anywhere is an alternative to server side, using reverse proxy.
You need that the server will return the right headers.